# SPHINX (search) : faking sql like on query

Tags: php, sql, sphinx

I am pretty new to sphinx, so I have a question about it.

Let's say I have a table called **tv_releases**

My sphinx.conf contains (small portion) :

```
source tv_releases
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = ---------
    sql_pass        = ---------
    sql_db          = --------
    sql_port        = 3306  

    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8

    #ingore for example ( delta updates ).
    sql_query_pre = REPLACE INTO title_counter SELECT 3, MAX(id) FROM tv_releases

    sql_query = SELECT id,rel ,tv_id,total_subs FROM tv_releases\

     #ignore for example ( delta updates).
     WHERE id<=( SELECT max_doc_id FROM title_counter WHERE counter_id=3 )

    sql_attr_uint = total_subs
    sql_attr_uint = tv_id
}
```

Indexing is fine , querying also.

Now sphinxapi ( php ) (portion)  :

```
$sp = new SphinxClient();
---...

$sp->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
$sp->SetArrayResult(true);
$sp->SetLimits ( 0, 100);
$sp->SetSortMode ( SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@relevance DESC, ....more options" );



  $results = $sp->Query('SEARCHTERM', 'tv_releases');
```

Now My question :

Let's say I have the following releases ( called rel in table ).

```
rel 1 : Name s01e02 Format-extradata
rel 2 : Name s01e03 Format-extradata
rel 3 : Name s02e05 Format-extradata
rel 4 : Name s02e06 Format-extradata
rel 5 : Name s03e06 Format-extradata
```

When my SEARCHTERM is "**Name S01**"

I want that the matching releases ( rel) ( ordered by Relevance )

will start with all the releases containing **Name s01e****

The problem is , it will not do this. 
A simple Like 'Name s01%' in sql will do that , but the whole point of sphinx was the speed.

Someone has a solution on how to accomplish the needed (search) results in sphinx ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

min_prefix_len (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-prefix-len) can help you.

Best wishes,
Sergey

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will take a look , hopefully it will resolve some query issues.